# I need help I can't pass an authentication token

Tags: django-rest-framework

```
class NotifyViewTests(APITestCase): 
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = APIRequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            name='test',            
            email='tes111t@test.com',
            password='test123',
        )       
   
        self.token = Token.objects.create(user=self.user)
        print(self.token.key)
           

def test_notify_api_success(self):             
    url = reverse('notify')       
    data = {
        "template_code": "interaction",
        "from_type": "user",
        "from_uuid": "5aef85d2-1445-11ee-be56-0242ac120002",
        "to_type": "user",
        "to_uuid": "6920f096-1445-11ee-be56-0242ac120002",
        "params": {
            "problem_title": "Titulo teste de um problema",
            "problem_desc": "Descrição teste de um problema"
        }                                  
    }                         
    self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user, token=self.token.key)
    response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')                        
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

---

Comment: Please paste your code in code blocks and provide detail. What have you tried and what went wrong?

Comment: Please for future explain in more details sir. not all people read your mind just through your code.

Answer (score 0):

If i can guess your import of the `force_authenticate` method, you are using the

```py
from rest_framework.test import force_authenticate
```

The you need to pass the request object to the method as the first argument, and the user as the second argument.

like below

```py
class NotifyViewTests(APITestCase): 
    def setUp(self): 
        self.factory = APIRequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user( name='test', email='tes111t@test.com', password='test123')
        self.token = Token.objects.create(user=self.user)
        print(self.token.key)
           

    def test_notify_api_success(self):             
        url = reverse('notify')       
        data = {
            "template_code": "interaction",
            "from_type": "user",
            "from_uuid": "5aef85d2-1445-11ee-be56-0242ac120002",
            "to_type": "user",
            "to_uuid": "6920f096-1445-11ee-be56-0242ac120002",
            "params": {
                "problem_title": "Titulo teste de um problema",
                "problem_desc": "Descrição teste de um problema"
            }                                  
        }                     
        # the request object should be django's request object
        # and Request will only authenticate if `SessionAuthentication` is in use.
        # so to get the request object, you need to make a request to the view
        request = self.factory.get(url)
        self.client.force_authenticate(request, user=self.user, token=self.token.key)
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')                        
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

and by the way i really recommend you to use `APIClient` instead of `APITestCase` and `APIRequestFactory` because it is much easier to use and it is more like a real request.

Comment: Excuse me follow the imports:
from rest_framework import status
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from rest_framework.test import force_authenticate
from apps.authentication.backends import User
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

Comment: I refactored the code and it is giving this error:
 File "/home/sergioleoncio/dev/api_notify/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/permissions.py", line 140, in has_permission
    return bool(request.user and request.user.is_authenticated)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'